# With this CSS-transformed flip card, how can I keep the back content accessible?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a flip card, both sides of which I want to be able to be able to click and edit with content editable, but I believe due to the CSS involved in achieving the flip transform, I can only access the front side; when the card is flipped, the back side can't be clicked on. How can I fix that?

```js
class Card {
  constructor() {
    this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    this.wrapper.className = "wrapper stowed";
    this.card = document.createElement("div");
    this.card.className = "card";
    this.front = document.createElement("div");
    this.front.className = "front";
    this.front.contentEditable = true;
    this.front.innerHTML = "Prompt";
    this.back = document.createElement("div");
    this.back.className = "back";
    this.back.contentEditable = true;
    this.back.innerHTML = "Answer";
    this.card.appendChild(this.front);
    this.card.appendChild(this.back);
    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.card);
    document.body.appendChild(this.wrapper);
  }
}

let card = new Card();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300');

body {
  font-size:25px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #39243b;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.card {
  transition: transform 2s;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: perspective(800px);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position:relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color:white;
}

.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: perspective(800px);
}

.wrapper:hover .card {
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(180deg);
}
```

As you can see, the issue is reproduced here perfectly, at least viewing in Chrome.

Comment: For anyone who saw the question as posted, note the edit. The issue is now reproduced correctly in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `backface-visibility: hidden` from `.card` and the problem goes away.

```js
class Card {
  constructor() {
    this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    this.wrapper.className = "wrapper stowed";
    this.card = document.createElement("div");
    this.card.className = "card";
    this.front = document.createElement("div");
    this.front.className = "front";
    this.front.contentEditable = true;
    this.front.innerHTML = "Prompt";
    this.back = document.createElement("div");
    this.back.className = "back";
    this.back.contentEditable = true;
    this.back.innerHTML = "Answer";
    this.card.appendChild(this.front);
    this.card.appendChild(this.back);
    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.card);
    document.body.appendChild(this.wrapper);
  }
}

let card = new Card();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300');

body {
  font-size:25px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #39243b;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.card {
  transition: transform 2s;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: perspective(800px);
  /*backface-visibility: hidden;*/
  position:relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color:white;
}

.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: perspective(800px);
}

.wrapper:hover .card {
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(180deg);
}
```